# API photo datetime taken

Tags: facebook-graph-api, datetime, facebook-fql, photo

I need to get photos from a album via Facebook API and I also need a datetime taken of the photos. Is is still not possible? Isn't it there some workaround? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook doesn't give you a taken time on their photos, only a time when the photo was uploaded to the Facebook system via the `created` field in FQL or `created_time` in the Graph API.

You could try downloading the largest version of a photo Facebook has on their system and checking for EXIF data. I doubt that there will be any.

Comment: Indeed you are right, I tried this a while ago and there is no EXIF data in the download image (or at least not the original data). I'm afraid you'll have to make due with the Upload-date... 

In some cases though a user can fill in the dates themselves when uploading. But I don't see this happen much...